# Haskell datatype syntax with manipulation, second part

Tags: haskell, types, syntax, functional-programming

Returning a datatype.
For instance, let's say that I had made a datatype:

```
data Something = Something Int [Char]
```

And, then I did some manipulation with the following function (the exact function of which is irrelevant):

```
manipulativeFunc::Something->[Something]
```

I keep getting these strange error messages that

```
Top level:
    No instance for (Show (Int -> IO ()))
        arising from use of 'print' at Top level
    Probable fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (Int -> IO ()))
    In a 'do' expression: print it
```

Note that I don't have any uses of print anywhere in my program, nor do I have any uses of IO. The data declaration and the `manipulativeFunc` are all I have on it.

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT: From commenters, I get the message that I may need to declare a Show instance for this task. So, what if I had

```
data Something = Something Int Int
```

Then how would I write a Show instance function for it?

Comment: Showing us more code would be helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to run this interactively in something like ghci? If so, there is an implicit print there. For items that don't inherit from Show, it will issue an error like yours.

Comment: @Kurt S yes, I am. I'm using ghci. That's how I'm used to testing my code with Haskell, what other approach would you recommend?

Comment: You must have some use of IO, otherwise the error would not involve `(Int -> IO ())` type. Pasting a part of code, or precise command you use would help. As others said, probably you're attempting to show a function. Try in GHCi "not" and "not True", the first will show you such error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the function `print`, the compiler needs to be able to convert a value into a `String`, which is ensured by the `Show` class. You try to display a function, and there is no `Show` instance defined for it.

In order to be able to display your `Something`, use

```
data Something = Something Int [Char] deriving Show
```

`manipulativeFunc` can't be displayed that way, but its result if you call it with an argument.

Comment: it's still not working. How would I define a Show instance for the datatype I declared? Better yet, how would I do something like data Something = Something Int Int?

Comment: Did you add the `deriving Show` after your `data` declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Every time you evaluate an expression in ghci, ghci will print the result of that expression. If the expression has a type which can't be printed, you get the above error message.

So the problem is that you entered an expression of type `Int -> IO ()`, which ghci can't print because it's a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a default Show instance:

```
data Something = Something Int Int deriving Show
```

or you can define your own:

```
instance Show Something where
    show (Something a b) = "<" ++ show a ++ " " ++ show b ++ ">"
```

But your problem is not related to Something not having a Show instance.

Please clarify whether you use `ghc`, `runhaskell` or `ghci`, and try to provide a complete minimal example. The following code works:

```
module Aaa where

data Something = Something Int Int

manipulativeFunc::Something->[Something]
manipulativeFunc x = [x]
```